# Есть ли аналог gulp.watch для Makefile?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, gulp, makefile

Работаю с большим количеством проектов, в каждом из которых я использую Gulp как менеджер задач и упаковщик файлов.

Плагинов для Gulp я использую много, поэтому папка node_modules в корне проекта достаточно большая. И, скорее всего, я не использую и 80% того кода плагинов, которые в этой папке лежат. Начал думать над серверной альтернативой для Gulp. С NodeJS я в принципе не работаю, поэтому не хотелось бы использовать его компоненты для задач, которые самого Node не требуют.

Решил, что решить задачу можно при помощи Makefile. Со сжатием и компрессией файлов все понятно - YUI-compressor. Но этого недостаточно. В Gulp очень удобная вещь Watcher. Один раз запустил команду и она, форсируя изменения файлов в указанных папках, выполняет команды по сжатию и минификации. А можно ли так же контролировать изменение файлов в Bash?

Comment: [Можно сделать перевод с английского](http://superuser.com/q/181517/379403).

Comment: @D-side, спасибо! Решение помогло. Переведу вечером на русский и оформлю как ответ.